# moving vertex is not deforming mesh?

Tags: mesh, edit-mode

so when i select a vertex and click g to move it, only the vertex/edges move, but the face/mesh stays in the same place. does anyone know how i can fix this/what i'm doing wrong? thanks!

[image: screenshot before i move it]

[image: screenshot after i move it]

Comment: not easy to understand, don't you have a second vertex at the same position? If so, delete it. But maybe share your file: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/